# Iphone Memory Warning issues

Tags: iphone, ios, memory-management

I am creating a app with MapView and UIImagePicker. I am displaying map on screen and its showing route as user moves on. User can capture images in between. I have two screens for that..

1. Showing map
2. Capturing image (This is pushed from screen 1)

When I go to screen 1 to screen 2. I show an ImagePicker and allow user to capture Images. When I pop back to screen 1 I `release` all objects and make it `nil`. This task generally done in `viewDidUnload` but I was getting memory issues so I did it when my view controller pops. So my all objects get release and nil as soon as I get done with them.

When I go to my login screen from map I am doing every thing I know like:

1. Removing views from super view
2. releasing all allated objects or retained objects (Including even NSString objects as well)
3. Setting `nil` value to all those object.

When I run the app by profiling and there is no run time leak avaiable But even in Activity Monitor my app's real memory continuesly get increase :(

After 10-12 images get captured I am getting `Received memory warning. Level=1` I am not even storing UIImage object in memory. I am writing this in document dir and storing string path only.

Please help me and guide me what else can be done to solve this issue.

**UPDATE**

While releasing objects on back button I am using:

```
- (void)releaseObjects {

    [mapViewNewTour setDelegate:nil];
    [mapViewNewTour removeFromSuperView];
    [mapViewNewTour release];
    mapViewNewTour = nil;
    [lblNavTitle release];
    lblNavTitle = nil;
    [btnEdit release];
    btnEdit = nil;
    [txtTourName release];
    txtTourName = nil;
    [vwTourName release];
    vwTourName = nil;
    [mutDictOfflineSharing release];
    mutDictOfflineSharing = nil;
    [mutArrImage release];
    mutArrImage = nil;

    [_routeLine release];
    _routeLine = nil;
    [_routeLineView release];
    _routeLineView = nil;
    [aLazyLoader release];
}
```

Comment: @basvk I have added code for the approach I am using to free memory.. Rest of all are normal alloc init and pusvc and present vc etc.

Comment: why u are still now using ARC

Comment: @SunilPandey I need to give support of ios 4.3 as well :( It may be my bad luck but I need to do this way only

Comment: if you can provide your image saving code then we may be able to help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you run instruments and see where memory is used. There are specific instruments for memory usage analysis. The instrument you will want is Activity monitor and VM tracker.

Also I recommend you double check that you are not running with NSZombieEnabled (check it in schemes), as it will cause memory warnings.

Comment: Yes running with zombies, especially on older hardware, will likely result in memory warnings as nothing is actually deleted.

Answer (score 3):

ARC is supported on 4.3 as well, so use it.

Your approach with a dedicated "releaseEverything" method is broken all the way - it shows lack of ownership tracking and is a hack at best.

`viewDidUnload` is now deprecated anyway and not called by the system in iOS 6 (which you should build against).

Don't fight the frameworks - do it the "right" way.

Comment: i also know this. but i don't know why apple has mention deployment target 5.x in this document http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/ObjCAvailabilityIndex/_index.html for ARC

Comment: The only limitation in iOS 4.3, is you can't use 'weak' qualifiers, as it requires a runtime to nil referenced objects. You can use _unsafe_unretained instead. I've recently made a transition to ARC in a project supporting iOS 4.3 and it can work nicely.

Comment: @Eiko thanks for reply.. how to use arc in 4.3?? Can you please provide some link on this..